# Flutter: How to use multiple streams combine

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

The question says it clearly, how to perform/combine multiple streams at the same time.

Let suppose we have a stream like

```
main() {
  print("Creating a sample stream...");
  Stream<String> stream = new Stream.fromFuture(getData());
  print("Created the stream");

  stream.listen((data) {
    print("DataReceived: "+data);
  }, onDone: () {
    print("Task Done");
  }, onError: (error) {
    print("Some Error");
  });
  
  print("code controller is here");
}

Future<String> getData() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)); //Mock delay 
  print("Fetched Data");
  return "This a test data";
}
```

Here Single stream performs & giving the callback, but what if I want multiple streams to perform at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

For it `StreamGroup` can be used to combine multiple streams

**Add Dependency:**

```
async: ^2.4.1
```

**Use StreamGroup:**

```
 void main() {
  Stream<String> stream1 = new Stream.fromFuture(getData(2));
  Stream<String> stream2 = new Stream.fromFuture(getData(4));
  Stream<String> stream3 = new Stream.fromFuture(getData(6));
  final result = StreamGroup.merge([
    stream1,
    stream2,
    stream3
  ]);
  result.listen((data) {
    print("DataReceived: " + data);
  });

}

Future<String> getData(int duration) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: duration)); //Mock delay
  return "This a test data";
}
```

**Output:**

```
I/flutter ( 5866): DataReceived: This a test data — Print after 2 seconds
I/flutter ( 5866): DataReceived: This a test data — Print after 4 seconds
I/flutter ( 5866): DataReceived: This a test data — Print after 6 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [rxdart package](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart):

**Depend on it:**

```
dependencies:
  rxdart: ^0.24.1
```

now you can use `Rx.merge` to simply merge multiple streams together:

```
Rx.merge([
  Rx.timer(1, Duration(days: 10)),
  Stream.value(2)
])
.listen(print); // prints 2, 1
```

rxdart also has other methods such as `combineLatest`. You can learn more about the different methods of merging multiple streams [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Rx-class.html).